# After the program almost finishes error appears — CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, destructor

I have this little dumb program what I have to do for my class. It works, it makes the right output, but at the end the Visual Studio says the program 
triggered a breakpoint and after I press continue it shows me this:

[ERROR1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUdbi.png)

After pressing "Ismét" (means again) it shows me the Visual Studio breakpoint window again, and after doing this for 5 times (it shows different errors each try) the program shuts down.

[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kIL8.png)

I found that the `free` command tries to clear out some trash, because the variable wasn't specified, but as you can see, in my case I always specify my `tomb` pointer.

#### class1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class kotprog {

private:

int a;
int b;


protected:
int *tomb = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
public:
kotprog(int c, int d) {
    a = c;
    b = d;
    tomb[0] = 0;
    tomb[1] = 0;
}
kotprog() {
    tomb[0] = 0;
    tomb[1] = 0;
}



void setA(int a) {
    this->a = a;
}
void setB(int b) {
    this->b = b;
}
int metodus1() {
    return a + b;
}
int metodus2() {
    return a - b;
}
int metodus3() {
    return a*b;
}
double metodus4() {
    return (double)a / (double)b;
}
void metodus5() {
    cout << "Egy teljesen buta kötelező program vagyok, mert teremtőmnek nem volt kedve többet foglalkozni velem. :(" << "\n";
    tomb[0] = this->a;
    tomb[1] = this->b;
    cout << "A tömb első eleme: " << tomb[0] << ". A tömb 2. eleme: " << tomb[1] << "." << "\n";
}

kotprog operator+(kotprog& b) {
    return kotprog(this->a + b.a, this->b + b.b);
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, kotprog&a) {

    return cout << "Az 1. paraméter: " << a.a << "\n" << "A második paraméter: " << a.b;

}
~kotprog() {
    free(tomb);

}
};
```

#### main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"class1.cpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {


kotprog* teszt = new kotprog(2,3);
kotprog teszt2(2,2);
kotprog teszt3(3, 3);
kotprog teszt4;



teszt->setA(12);
teszt->setB(12);

cout << "1. metódus eredménye: " << teszt->metodus1() << "\n";
cout << "2. metódus eredménye: " << teszt->metodus2() << "\n";
cout << "3. metódus eredménye: " << teszt->metodus3() << "\n";
cout << "4. metódus eredménye: " << teszt->metodus4() << "\n";
teszt->metodus5();

teszt4 = teszt2 + teszt3;
cout << "A teszt4 eredménye: " << "\n" << teszt4;
delete teszt;
}
```

Comment: Google "c++ rule of three".  You are violating it.

Comment: You should generally avoid using `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ programs.  Using them complicates the memory management — witness the problems you're encountering.  Given that `tomb` is a pointer to a fixed size array of 3 integers, why do dynamic allocation at all?  Simply make it `int tomb[3];` and avoid all the dynamic memory allocation problems.

Comment: I use it because i have to, if this program would have a purpose i wouldn't do it this way, i have to use one dynamic allocated variable at least to complete the task.